# Can I install Ubuntu into a Windows Dynamic Volume?

Tags: installation, windows

I have a hp 6166tx laptop with factory fitted Windows 7 home Edition. I tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows, in a shrink volume(which is dynamic type). But it gives an error in the end and stops the installer.

Is it possible to install ubuntu into a Windows Dynamic Volume? If it is, then how? Please help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? ("The request isn't supported" from bcdedit.exe)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

Answer (score 4):

It is **not** possible to install Ubuntu on a dynamic volume/logical partition, you need a primary partition to install Ubuntu. Have you tried instead, installing Ubuntu on [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)? I can assure you the results will be much better.

Comment: Also only way to convert dynamic disk to basic disk is to delete all partition and convert.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: no.

Does Wubi (Windows Ubuntu Installer) not suit your needs? It's not the same as running Ubuntu natively, but I've heard good things about it.