# Partitions not showing while installing (K)ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, kubuntu

Im trying to install Kubuntu 14.04 along-side Windows 7 x64 but there are problems in Disk Setup section, installer does not show my drives properly as they are, i left drive empty to install Kubuntu but this drive does not shown at all and all drives are listed some way un-regular.

this is how my drives really are:

[image]

i want to install Kubuntu in my drive D but this is how Disk Setup is showing my drives:

[image]

and when i click on manual:

[image]

i even shrink-ed my drive D to assigning for root, home and swap but there are bot shown to be chosen.
where is the problem? how can i tell installer to assign the drives that i want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partitions created in Windows are not showing in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409561/partitions-created-in-windows-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your drive is partitioned as a ["Dynamic Disk"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dynamic_disks). [Ubuntu can not be installed on a dynamic disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118560/can-i-install-ubuntu-into-a-windows-dynamic-volume). You will need to convert the Ubuntu partitions to "basic partitions" in Windows before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: This is outside my comfort zone, but should @Armin be using NTFS for his Kubuntu drive? I would have [thought not](http://askubuntu.com/q/123808/38585).

Comment: @Davïd It does not matter. If he selects that partition in the Ubuntu installer, the installer will change the partition type to "Linux" and reformat it to ext4. Resizing and creating a partition like this on Windows (or OS X) is a useful trick, since the Windows and OS X tools can resize all of their own native dynamic partitions and file systems, whereas gparted can't resize Windows/OS X Dynamic Disks (or CoreStorage), and does not fully support HFS+. The Windows/OS X native tools are also arguably less likely to have compatibility problems with Windows/OS X storage and file systems.