# Ubuntu installer doesn't detect partition on Win7 (Warning: Can't have a partition outside the disk!)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, partitioning

I tried to look it up on the forum but I can't find a solution.
I just got a PC laptop (I come from Mac…) installed Win7 and partition my hd in 3 parts, one for Win7, one unformatted for Ubuntu, and one NTFS for data.
The Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize the partitions though. What can I do?
My goal is to have a dual boot. Thank you so much!

[Gparted screenshot](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1452/infofp.png) note **Warning: Can't have a partition outside the disk!**

Comment: @Tim - the assumed answer is 'yes', as that is the standard install disk... user287418, could you please add a screenshot of the disk layout as shown in [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/)

Comment: like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/wCxpN.png

Comment: No, thats what the installer shows (it may show the same thing anyway) - when booting from the disc, select 'Try Ubuntu', and then search for and open GParted. It'll look like [this]( http://i.stack.imgur.com/wmnQG.png) (not quite, thats an already set up dual boot). You can also use it as said in Tim's answer.

Comment: Ok, in gparted it give me an unallocated 465.76GiB on /dev/sda and 980MB fat32 on /dev/sdb which is probably the usb flash drive

Comment: Have a look at [Partitions not showing while installing (K)ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474812/partitions-not-showing-while-installing-kubuntu-14-04/474881#474881). If it does not solve your problem, then post a screenshot of the partitions in Windows Disk Management (like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/THo5q.jpg))

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to [partition it from the live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition), follow the link to the ubuntu HowtoPartition page.

Comment: I read it but they assume I have a blank hard drive while I already have Win7 on it

Comment: Do you have the Live CD?

Comment: Yes I do. It says free space 500107 MB. Doesn't see the partitions at all

Comment: Is that in gparted or the install?

Comment: mmmm I don't know! :)

Comment: I think I have gpt

Comment: OK. Can you post a screenshot online (dropbox / gdrive / fb) and send the link?

Comment: basically it's like this http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1452/infofp.png

Comment: Can you boot W7? If so, can you create an EXT4 partition in it?

Comment: I just did it with Minitool. Still doesn't show up on Ubuntu

Comment: Do you still have the W7 install CD and a backup of your data on W7? If so, go ahead and make an EXT4 partition using Gparted, keep it small (~15GB), we can change and reinstall ubuntu later if it works. Then install ubuntu on it.

Comment: ok, I just deleted everything! Geez! It's ok. I will format properly the hard drive now. How can I format it to install both Ubuntu and Win7?

Comment: You need a swap space the size of your Ram, and then a EXT4 partition for Ubuntu and a NTFS for W7. I would suggest installing Ubuntu first, and using Gparted to partition it. I'm no expert, so you should chech https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot first.