# Windows partition recognized as unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, partitioning

I am new to Linux.
I was trying to dual boot windows 8.1 and ubuntu when I came across this: ubuntu installer won't recognize windows as an OS and the C drive is recognized as "unallocated space" by ubuntu. How can I install Ubuntu alongside windows? I tried installing before, when windows 8 was UEFI, I now reinstalled windows 8 and it's not UEFI now, what should I do?

Comment: anyone? please, I am quite desperate getting an answer now

Comment: Have a look at [Partitions not showing while installing (K)ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474812/partitions-not-showing-while-installing-kubuntu-14-04/474881#474881). If it does not solve your problem, then post a screenshot of the partitions in Windows Disk Management (like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/THo5q.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize your C partition under Windows using the built-in disk management (just use the search function of Windows 8). Then select your C drive, right-click on it and choose `Shrink Volume...`. You will have to enter the amount of MB you want to shrink your C drive. Note that you have to leave some free disk space for Windows. Then reboot and repeat the installation of ubuntu; now the free space will be recognized by the installation routine.